# Why does Convert.ToString format doubles in this way?

Tags: c#

Consider the following code:

```
var rateUsed = 0.00000001;
var rateUsedConvertToString = Convert.ToString(rateUsed);
var rateUsedToString = rateUsed.ToString();
```

Instead of my strings being "0.00000001", they are both "1E-08". I don't have control over the initial type of rateUsed, it is a double, and I want the exact string representation of the double.

Why does this happen, and how would I get 0.00000001 as a string, if this started off as a double value?

Comment: Try giving it an explicit type for rateUsed. It may be inferring a different type than you are expecting.

Comment: Anyone care to explain why the downvoting?

Comment: This isn't about accuracy; 1E-08 is ***exactly*** 0.00000001; this is simply a formatting question.

Comment: @StingyJack Incorrect, floating point literals are assumed to be doubles unless an `f` is added. OP, See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx

Comment: @StingyJack I assume the downvoting is because the question has been asked many times and shows no effort in finding an answer.

Comment: @Rotem - just trying to help him work towards an answer instead of getting rabidly downvoted

Comment: @StringyJack: `var rateUsed = 0.00000001; Console.WriteLine(rateUsed.GetType().Name); // Double`

Comment: @Rotem Can you provide a link?

Comment: @JMK I did: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx See all the examples at the bottom of the page.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546113/double-to-string-conversion-without-scientific-notation) and [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964737/double-tostring-no-scientific-notation) look like the same question

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate, I did actually look, I just wasn't aware of the term 'scientific notation', now I know, cheers guys!

Comment: @JMK It's also advisable to actually look at documentation before immediately asking question. I don't know what it is with the aversion to reading documentation. If you look at the [MSDN page for Convert.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring.aspx) you'd find [ToString(double value, IFormatProvider provider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131010.aspx) which even demonstrates this exact behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a specific format, then you need to tell it what you want via the parameter. The available [standard formats are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), or you can use [custom formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx). Pass your chosen format to either `ToString(format)` or `Convert.ToString(value, format)`.

Note; 1E-8 is exactly 0.00000001 - that is simply using exponential notation, i.e. this is 1×10<sup>-8</sup>

The default format is "general" which is described as:

> Result: The most compact of either fixed-point or scientific notation

So yes, sometimes it will use scientific (aka exponential) notation - specifically, it will do so whenever that is shorter than the fixed-point notation. Maybe try using `.ToString("F")`

Answer (score 2):

You may want to start off looking at [When does Double.ToString() return a value in scientific notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977746/when-does-double-tostring-return-a-value-in-scientific-notation)

With that said, as @MarcGravell inferred, `1E-08`=`0.00000001`, it's just been displayed in scientific notation. If you're looking for something to output as a decimal number (typical) you may want to look in to formatting it differently. Such as:

```
var rateUsed = 0.00000001;
var rateUsedToStringFormatted = rateUsed.ToString("0.########"); // 0.00000001
```

Another option is to create a custom [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx)/[`ICustomFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter.aspx) which would perform this conversion consistently. Then, instead of using `.ToString("0.########")` everywhere, you could supply `.ToString(MyDoubleFormatter)` for a more consistent output (and, should you change it at a later date, you're doing so in one location).

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use the [fixed-point ("F") format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#FFormatString) with a [different overload of `ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx), one which accepts the format specifier string:

```
int num = 175;
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("F", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));  // 175.00
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("F3", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // 175.000
```

Alternatively, you can use a [custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("00000.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // 00175.00
```

Additionally, as shown in these examples, whenever you are converting values to their text representations, consider using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` for data which should be stored independently of the current thread's culture (like when writing data to a file, for example).