# Convert decimal to scientific when certain character count is reached

Tags: c#

I'm making a calculator. I've got a textbox which shows the output calculations (`txtdisplay.Text`). But it only fits 8 characters so if I have a calculation with more than 8 characters it will be cut off and cannot be seen.

How do i make my result (e.g 120000000) into (1.2e+10) whenever the amount of **characters** reaches over 8?

Note that it's actually two questions, how do I make something happen when a textbox reaches 9 characters and how do I subsequently convert the content of the textbox to a scientific notation?

Comment: So what if I type `1234567891`? It would be `1.234567891e+9`, which that output is more than 9 characters.

Comment: Also why would you limit your textbox to only 8 characters?

Comment: @gunr2171 fair point i noticed halfway through writing that that would be an issue as wel, guess i have to find a way to round off? but i'm doing one issue at a time.
It's limited to 8 characters because i've got my font set to 48 and want it to be a basic looking calculator (like the windows one) and not a calculator with a 2 page long result. Or is this not what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a format specifier when converting the double to a string. The "G" format specifier uses the shorter of fixed-point and scientific notation. You can specify a maximum number of digits for the cutoff using "G#". So, for example to limit the number to 8 digits use:

```
double x = 120000000;
string text  = x.ToString("G8"); // 1.2E+08
```

If you really want a limited number of characters you could do something like this:

```
private static string FormatDouble(double d)
{
    string text = d.ToString();
    return text.Length > 8 ? d.ToString("0.#E+0") : text;
}
```

Note that 8 characters is extremely limited. You've got to display the mantissa's sign, exponent (up to 3 characters), exponent's sign, decimal separator, "E", which can be up to 7 characters without even considering the mantissa itself.

Comment: Your code outputs `12000000`. Although the input example in the question works with this code (you are missing one 0).

Comment: @gunr2171 It all depends on the number of digits you want. I think the OP wants more than 2 digits though, since it says over 8. I changed the input since that was exactly 8 which would show in fixed-point.

Comment: Great piece of information and a clean way of doing it, but i'm afraid  can't implement it as i have a greatly fluctuating double and it has to be done when the text reaches over 8 characters which is best to be done in the text.changed handler i believe.

Comment: @Daniel I posted an alternative, maybe you can use that. I don't see how TextChanged is going to be used here. You should formatting the number before putting it into the text box.

Comment: @mikez Thanks for the input and i understand the code i think, or atleast the main idea. But when i try and implement it myself i try this : double output = FormatDouble(result);
where result is a double. and it gives me the error can't convert string to double.
Now when i add this code to convert the result to a string like this : string testresult = Convert.ToString(result); and then do the same. double output = FormatDouble(testresult); it gives me two errors, now it says can't convert string to double and the best overload method for (formatdouble) has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

This code converts you number to scintific notation:

```
yournumber.ToString("G2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

This code can help you to determine that text was changed:

```
textBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);

...    

private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//code to handle changes
}
```

Comment: Not quiet sure what's going on here but that's probably my own incompetence. Visual studio 2013 doesn't seem to recognize invariantculture nor cultureinfo and where would i put the += new eventhandler?

Comment: @Daniel you should add using System.Globalization; to use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Comment: @Daniel adding event handlers could be put to your form constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void CalcTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     int testInt = 0;

     if (((TextBox)sender).Text.Length > 8 && int.TryParse(((TextBox)sender).Text, out testInt))
     {
        ((TextBox)sender).Text = String.Format("{0:E2}", testInt); 
     }
 }
```

Attach to the TextChanged Event, and set it there.

Comment: i corrected the tryparse in the if ( should be , **out** testInt)
but even with that corrected and no errors showing in the code, when i run it and reach over 8 characters it gives an error at the line ((textbox)sender).text = string.format("{0:E2}"); saying that the index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list. honestly not a clue what this could be reffering to

Comment: fixed the out. What text are you entering? I just tested this, and it works fine.

Comment: @Daniel can you post what text you are entering? I just tested this, and it works fine.

Comment: I just press a number (Eg 5) on my numpad of the calculator 9 times, so 5 shows up and then another till it ends up with 9. The second it does it shows 555555555 and it gives the error

Comment: @Daniel What is the value of the integer being passed into the STring.Format function?

Comment: Does it not tryparse textbox.text into the testint? if so the value would be 5555555555 even though any value that i put in gives the error

Comment: @Daniel It should be, but I suspect something is going wrong with it in your code. Can you debug and confirm that testInt does have a value at that line?

Answer (score 0):

`Double.ToString()` provides a level of this capability out of the box.  The default capability doesn't seem to suit your particular issue.  You could use a specific formatting such as `Double.ToString("G8", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`, but this may also be insuffient.  You may need to create your own implementation of `IFormatProvider` to satisfy your needs.

Please consider the following resources:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045.aspx

[When does Double.ToString() return a value in scientific notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977746/when-does-double-tostring-return-a-value-in-scientific-notation)