# best way to check if double has exponential notation

Tags: c#, double

what is the best way to check if a double has an exponential notation?
is there a way to do it without converting it to string?

my best solution so far is

```
var asString = doubleValue.ToString();
var containsExpNotation = asString.Contains('e') || asString.Contains('E')
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: That could work, but internally they all do. What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You can use formatters to avoid that notation when formatting the value to a string.  Otherwise you're basically just checking if the value has a very large or very small magnitude.

Comment: In fact, I want to decide whether to round a number whether it has an exponential notation (UI consideration, trying to avoid too long numbers)
there may be a better solution but I need something simple for a quick fix

Comment: @LiorSwisa Then the question is entirely based on how many digits your particular UI has space to render, which none of us can tell you.

Comment: Internally, a double is stored in a binary structure, not in scientific notation. It might be *expressed* in scientific notation when converted to a string (explicitly or implicitly). So I think the question you really want to ask it [when does `double.ToString()` return a value in scientific notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977746/when-does-double-tostring-return-a-value-in-scientific-notation)

Comment: @JohnWu Well, internally floating point numbers are in fact stored as an exponent and a mantissa (which is functionally scientific notation) although it's in base 2 not base 10.  Not that the mechanism by which it's stored has anything to do with how it's rendered as a string, as you said.

Comment: To elaborate on @JohnWu's point.  A `double` has no notation associated with it.  It's only when it's rendered as a string that it has a _notation_.  How it's rendered has nothing to do with how many significant figures it has or how large the exponent is.  For example, `Math.PI.ToString("E2");` results in a string that looks like `"3.14E+000"`

Answer (score 1):

Every floating point number can be written in scientific notation (using e or E). You can use the format arguments to specify whether you want that or not:

```cs
doubleValue.ToString(); // same as "G"
doubleValue.ToString("G"); // Format as floating point, unless more than 15 digits would be required, in which case scientific notation is used
doubleValue.ToString("E"); // Use scientific notation
doubleValue.ToString("F"); // Use floating point notation
```

So it's all in your hands whether a number is represented with an exponent or not.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings for the full list of options.

Comment: from what I saw in the documentation G chooses the most compact way to write a number (so for example 0.00001 will be 1E-05, 
thanks!

Comment: Yea, G is a bit tricky (you can also choose the number of digits). Most of the time, I use the "F" specifier together with a number, e.g. "F2", because I know that the value is within an useful range for this.